# как убрать вывод fatal в ansible

Tags: ansible

если task не выполняется, выдает ошибку fatal, но мне не нужно чтобы она отображалась на экране.

Comment: Эммм... `ignore_errors: yes`?

Comment: ignore_errors - это таски продолжат дальше работать, нашел callback плагин методы переопределяешь и настраиваешь вывод как тебе нужно